# How to listen for Firebase setValue completion

Tags: java, android, database, multithreading, firebase

I would like to set up something like a groupchat in Firebase.
If you have the correct group ID, you can join.

The problem is that Firebase references always exist. They are created dynamically. To allow some error checking in the joining process, I want to add the user who created the new database entry to a table of users.

```
public void createParty() {

    // you need to be signed in to create a party
    assertState(DBState.SignedIn);

    // create a new party
    ourPartyDatabaseReference = partiesDatabaseReference.push();
    usersDatabaseReference = ourPartyDatabaseReference.child("users");

    // write our user to the table of users, now the ourPartyReference actually exists
    // and if you look for existing users, you will always find at least the original creator
    Task initTask = usersDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(true);
```

After this has been done, I call a helper method `connectToParty` to set up a few references and change the state of the database connection to `DBState.Connected`. Now you can take the key of the party and transmit it to other users. With key I mean the name in firebase.

The problem is: Other users need to check whether they used a valid key to connect. They do this by checking if there is data under `key/users`. So the party is only valid if the first user has been successfully written to the database.

Sometimes the write process takes very long, sometimes it seems to fail completely. So I've set up listeners:

```
Task initTask = usersDatabaseReference.child(user.getUid()).setValue(true);

initTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object o) {
        connectToParty();
    }
});

initTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        changeState(DBState.SignedIn, DBTransition.Failure);
    }
});
```

This is covered by a test. The test sets up a connection, signs in and creates a party. If the party is created within a specific timeout, the test passes.

9 out of 10 times this works without a problem.
But sometimes the test fails.

This has nothing to do with the timeout being to short. The callbacks from the task are simply not called.
I read that this callback only works if your connection is online.

So I added `firebaseDatabase.goOnline();` to my code, just before the task. But that doesn't help.

I'm connected to the internet over LAN. All the other tests pass, and they need to access firebase, too. For example for the sign-in process.

What is the correct way to write a value to the database and wait for the write to complete ?

Comment: What's the error when the test fails?

Comment: It's a timeout. I'm waiting 10 seconds for the callback, then the test fails.

Comment: So neither of the two are called

Comment: If neither the success listener or failure listener is called, that means that the client hasn't heard a response from the server yet. If you're running this in a unit test, 10 seconds seems rather optimistic. Try expanding it to 1-2 minutes to see if that is indeed the reason for the behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the [offical documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback) says:

> If you'd like to know when your data has been committed, you can add a completion listener. Both setValue() and updateChildren() take an optional completion listener that is called when the write has been committed to the database.

This is a simple example:

```
ref.setValue("I'm writing data to a Firebase database", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data could not be saved. " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `setPersistenceEnabled(true);`? This means that you can keep the data from the database in two places: in memory and/or on disk. You can also use `keepSynced(true)` which means that the data in the app will always be up to date with what's in the database on the server (as long as there is a network connection).

Comment: I've tried the two. The problem no longer occured. I've removed the new code, the problem no longer occured. It's extremely hard to debug this non-deterministic behaviour.

Comment: I understand you. It's a little bit harder but i think this is the only way to achieve this. Do you think that my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes, your answer helped me ;).
I'll take some more time for testing and if I see that the error never occurs in connection with your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Ok lhk. Cheers!

Comment: Is there everything alright? Can i help you with other informations?

Comment: Hi Alex, unfortunately, the problem is still not fixed. The missing callbacks still occur sometimes (extremely rarely). It is almost impossible to debug this properly. Now I've found a new bug, which happens deterministically for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47079227/firebase-callbacks-work-during-testing-but-not-during-runtime

Comment: Do you think that my answer for this question helped you in any way?

Comment: I think your answer was a good idea, so I already did upvote it ;)  but the problem is not solved. The tests still fail sometimes, even with your code. So I can't accept your answer

Comment: Hi Alex, with both keepSynced and setPersistenceEnabled(true) this approach doesnot work out for me.

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat Please post a fresh question, so me or other user can help you.

Answer (score 10):

For the Kotlin users, you can use this

```
firebaeRef.setValue("your_value", { error, ref ->
            //setValue operation is done, you'll get null in errror and ref is the path reference for firebase database
        })
```

Here, `firebaeRef` is the reference to the node/child who's value is set and `your_value` is the value to be set.

Answer (score 0):

you can consider adding listeners for each of the possible return results.

```
  ref.child(user.getUid()).setValue(true)
        .addOnFailureListener {
            print("Update failed: $it") 
        }.addOnCanceledListener {
            print("Update canceled") 
        }.addOnSuccessListener {
            print("Update completed ")
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Just put your code in try catch block and see your error in Toast

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText t=findViewById(R.id.edittext);

              String data=t.getText().toString();

                try {
                    ref.setValue(data);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        
            }
        });
```