# Firebase continously adding data on real time database Android 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, insert

I am trying to make a registration process on `Android 3.0.1` using Firebase Real-time database. Everything is completed. I can add values to the database. But the problem is when I click the Sign-Up button it continuously adding same data. Intent not working at all. Can anyone help?

[image: Code]

[image: Database]

Comment: put the code as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the `push()` inside a *listener* which means that every time you `push()` the *listener* is called again - it is listening for any update, not just the update performed inside it.

You just need to pull the `push()` outside the listener. i.e. delete the listener altogether.

If you want to  listen for the completion of `push().set()` just add a completion listener to the event or (the easiest way) just use the `set` method's parameter for completion listener like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829877/7556011)

Or if you want to use the same setup you can use a `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` for the push key which is retrieved by appending `getKey()` to the `push().set()`, but I would recommend the first method over this one.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`. Thanks a lot.