# the data is submitted in firebase once in each run

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am inserting data into my firebase realtime database. I wrote a code for it. however, when i run the program, first thing it will insert and submit the data correctly, but when I move in the same run to other activity for example to login, and came back to insert other data, it will not insert it.

when I want to insert a data in my firebase, each time I must re-install the program and install it again and do it at the first,

Here is my code

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fill_request_page);
    firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    Title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
    Content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Content);
    insert =(Button) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    status=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.statustxt);
    edittxtDate =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtDate);
    edittxtTime =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtTime);
    edittxtExpDate=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxtExpDate);
    imagebtnDate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtnDate);
    imagebtnTime = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtnTime);
    imagebtnExpDate=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebtnExpDate);
    location = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.location);
    typeof=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.typeof);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref1 = database.getReference("requests");



    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            btnInsert1();
        }
    });


private void getValues(){
    request1.setTitle(Title.getText().toString());
    request1.setContent(Content.getText().toString());
    request1.setDate(edittxtDate.getText().toString());
    request1.setTime(edittxtTime.getText().toString());
    request1.setLocation(location.getSelectedItem().toString());
    request1.setTypeof(typeof.getSelectedItem().toString());
    request1.setExpDate(edittxtExpDate.getText().toString());
    request1.setStatus(status.getText().toString());
}
private void btnInsert1(){

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref1 = database.getReference("requests");
    DatabaseReference ref2=ref1.push();
    String id=ref2.getKey();
    request1 =new requests();
    getValues();
    ref1.child(id).setValue(request1);
    Toast.makeText(FillRequestPage.this,"Data inserted....",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Do you click the button again when you come back to the activity? If so, did you run the code in a debugger and check if your `btnInsert1()` method gets triggered?

Comment: I think the problem in my btnInsert method, beacuse I have another button in same activity works well without re-run the program

Comment: the athor button is for uploading image in firebase, and it works correctly without the need of re-run the code

Comment: You are adding data only on button click?

Comment: Yes , I heve 4 EditTexts to allow the user insert the information. and once the user press the button it must be inserted to firebase

Comment: I just found that I must Ununstall the program and re- install it to insert new data :) ,, please help me

Comment: I don't immediately see anything wrong with the `btnInsert1` method. I recommend running the code in a debugger and seeing if `btnInsert1` gets triggered the second time. If so, step through and check all variables. If that doesn't show anything, add a completion listener to your `setValue` call, to see if you are getting an error back from the server as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829749/how-to-listen-for-firebase-setvalue-completion

Comment: my problem was from the firebase its self, the access is denied , I just edited the Rules So the user can read and write to my database and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem was from the firebase its self, the access is denied , I just edited the Rules So the user can read and write to my database and it works!