# Prevent ValueEventListener From Listening to Local Changes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a `ValueEventListener` in my `Android` App which gets triggered by the client's side. 
I'd like to trigger this listener only when the `data` has received by the server.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get a listener that is only triggered for server-side data. It's typically also considered an anti-pattern; in a well developed app, it's best to simply show the latest data.

What you *can* do is to [use a completion listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829749/how-to-listen-for-firebase-setvalue-completion), to detect when the write has completed. That way you know your value has been committed (or rejected) on the server.