# I want two create two functions in one button

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

I am working on an app which would store data in `Firebase`. The issue is that when I **click** submit, the data **stays** on the form. I need when I click submit that it returns to the home screen.

I tried using the start activity method like I did when I wanted to move from `MainActivity` to another class. It would work but then my data will not be saved.

I am grateful for any assistance. Thanks in advance!

```
buttonSubmitReport.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            reports.setDate(textDate.getText().toString().trim());
            reports.setTime(textTime.getText().toString().trim());
            reports.setReport(editRep.getText().toString().trim());

            reff.push().setValue(reports);
                    reff.child(String.valueOf(maxID+1)).setValue("Reports");
                    Toast.makeText(submitReport.this,"Thanks for the information!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: hello ! you can achieve your functionality using a flag just like i will explain you...first take a boolean variable and set it false..after that on button click call method to store data and after storing data set boolean flag true and check if(flag) means flag is true then move to another activity...thats it!!! ;)

Comment: have you redirect back to previous activity when data stored successfully in firebase console ?

Comment: override setvalue complete listener when data is successfully uploaded than redirect to other activity, for more info have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829877/5110595)

Comment: @DharaJani thats my issue. I need it to redirect after storing data successfully. but so far it doesn't

Comment: @Shane you have to code for startActivity using intent when data is inserted successfully :)

Comment: show how you tried with `startActivity()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am getting from your problem is that you have one activity from there you are starting another activity for editing the details and on click of some button, you want to save those details and come back to previous activity, right?
To do this just add some listener to that and when it completed simply finish the activity

```
buttonSubmitReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        reports.setDate(textDate.getText().toString().trim());
        reports.setTime(textTime.getText().toString().trim());
        reports.setReport(editRep.getText().toString().trim());

        reff.push().setValue(reports);

        reff.child(String.valueOf(maxID + 1)).setValue("Reports")
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        // Write was successful!, here either finish or move to another activity
                        Toast.makeText(submitReport.this, "Thanks for the information!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Write failed
                        Toast.makeText(submitReport.this, "Failed to store the data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    });
```

Comment: Might be better to create one instance of `OnSuccessListener` and one of `OnFailureListener` instead of creating a _new_ one with every button click. This comment is for OP; I don't expect answerers to do all that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions @Kartik sure we can do so, that was just a example on how to do something, improvements is next thing to do and for most of the cases it is not a problem because once it success it will get finish so no new button click.
thanks

Comment: oh yes, it's the form submit button

Comment: thanks for the assistance. for some reason the finish method never came in my mind till I saw your response. I added finish() after the toast and it works smooth. back to the main screen.

Comment: @Shane Great, that it helped you, Please upvote so that it helps others also.

Comment: @vikaskumar unfortunately I dont have enough reputation to leave feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase value update listener, Once value update performs the operation. 
Or you can use the firebase transaction handler.

```
override fun onComplete(dataBaseError: DatabaseError?, status: Boolean, snapShot: DataSnapshot?) {
            //Operation complete call back
        }

        override fun doTransaction(data: MutableData): Transaction.Result {
            //Perform your operation here
            return Transaction.success(data)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it once if possible

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        buttonSubmitReport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        InsertData();

                        ReportsID = Fetch Reports Id and use condition is empty or not
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(ReportsID)) {
                            InsertData();
                        } else {
                            //---Start Activity
                        }
                    }
        });

    }

    public bool InsertData()
    {
        reports.setDate(textDate.getText().toString().trim());
        reports.setTime(textTime.getText().toString().trim());
        reports.setReport(editRep.getText().toString().trim());

        reff.push().setValue(reports);
        reff.child(String.valueOf(maxID+1)).setValue("Reports");
        Toast.makeText(submitReport.this,"Thanks for the information!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```