# How to achieve delivery status in firebase realtime chat in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'd like to implement a 'delivery' feature in my Firebase chat messaging app like other chat apps. Can you kindly advise how can I achieve.

Comment: Look for https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829877/16867144