# Firebase Realtime database does not show the values added to it..only displays null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've added all the dependencies and all, but the data is still not displaying on the firebase realtime
database screen. Ot shows only null. So i've added the code which uses the firebase.

The signup screen code   :

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextInputLayout regName, regUsername, regPassword, regEmail, regPhoneno;
    Button regBtn, regLoginbtn;
    FirebaseDatabase rootNode;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        regName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        regUsername = findViewById(R.id.username);
        regPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        regEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        regPhoneno = findViewById(R.id.PhoneNo);
        regBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        regLoginbtn = findViewById(R.id.button2);

        regBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String name = Objects.requireNonNull(regName.getEditText()).getText().toString();
                String username = Objects.requireNonNull(regUsername.getEditText()).getText().toString();
                String password = Objects.requireNonNull(regPassword.getEditText()).getText().toString();
                String email = Objects.requireNonNull(regEmail.getEditText()).getText().toString();
                String phoneNo = Objects.requireNonNull(regPhoneno.getEditText()).getText().toString();

                UserHelperClass helperClass = new UserHelperClass(name, password, username,  email, phoneNo);
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("my").child("users").setValue(helperClass);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

> the class to get the data from app

```
package com.example.medilyf;

public class UserHelperClass {

    String name, password, username, email, phonenno;

    public UserHelperClass() {

    }

    public UserHelperClass(String name, String password, String username, String email, String phonenno) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.phonenno = phonenno;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhonenno() {
        return phonenno;
    }

    public void setPhonenno(String phonenno) {
        this.phonenno = phonenno;
    }
}
```

build.gradle project:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
         // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle app:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'

}
[enter image description here][1]
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.medilyf"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:15.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you check the logcat output for when `setValue` runs, is there any error message?

Comment: Have you tried to attach a listener to the `.setValue(helperClass)` operation? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because UserHelperClass object is null. Don't use the overloaded constructor to set values instead use setters of model class.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `OnCompletelistener` after the setValue and see the error.

For reference : https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.CompletionListener

Comment: inside the .setValue("your_value") add one more parameter, 
`.setValue("your_value(helperClass)",new OnCompleteListener(){ 
// ovveride functions here
})`
Here is a quick example of that https://stackoverflow.com/a/46829877/12823018